# replacement for `mk-table-checksum --scheme`

Tags: command-line, mysql, mariadb, sql

After upgrading to LTS 16.04.1, the `mk-table-checksum --scheme` generates errors, so tried to find a newer version, but can only find `pt-table-checksum`, and it doesn't have a `--scheme`-option.

Also found some information on a `mysqldiff`, but it looked like it only could compare 2 currently online databases.

The benefits from mk that I want to keep, I could make a checksum per table, and then later compare it with its current table, on either the same machine, or on another server.

Is there another tool that can do this?
(or maybe I should just try to patch the old mk? it complains about 'Redundant argument in sprintf' from rows like `my $result = sprintf('%03d%03d%03d', $str =~ m/(\d+)/g);`